# How to flatten a SQL statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have a case statement

```
Select customer, group, case when group = one then 'A' else 'B' end as Indicator FROM TABLE1
```

How do I "flatten" the indicator so for each customer I have 2 column for each indicator type (Goal Table)

Current Table:

| Customer | Group | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joh | One | A |
| Joh | Two | B |
| Jane | One | A |
| Jane | Two | B |

Goal Table:

| Customer | Indicator1 | Indicator2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joh | A | B |
| Jane | A | B |

Comment: so there will be Indicator3? if you have a indicator "C" in the raw table?

Answer (score 1):

Since values are being hard-coded ('A','B') for indicator column, we can use max, as it will yield one value only -

```
with data_cte(Customer,Group_1,Indicator) as(
select * from values
('Joh','One','A'),
('Joh','Two','B'),
('Jane','One','A'),
('Jane','Two','B')
)select d.customer
,max(case when d.group_1 = 'One' then 'A' end) as indicator1
,max(case when d.group_1 = 'Two' then 'B' end) as indicator2
from data_cte d
group by d.customer;
```

Comment: +1 Just was i was about to answer, but you got first :-). Here is a working fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d1c6765e26ef3cc3fe67c1039403894c

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKrikorev. I gave from snowflake. That is the issue when question poster tags multiple DBs.

Answer (score 0):

The form of Pankaj's answer is good if you have fixed group's, but his code has the indicator values hard coded, this it should look like:

```
with data_cte(Customer, Group_1, Indicator) as (
    select * 
    from values
        ('Joh','One','A'),
        ('Joh','Two','B'),
        ('Jane','One','A'),
        ('Jane','Two','B')
)
select 
    d.customer
    ,max(case when d.group_1 = 'One' then d.indicator end) as indicator1
    ,max(case when d.group_1 = 'Two' then d.indicator end) as indicator2
from data_cte as d
group by 1;
```

The CASE in the MAX can be swapped for a IFF in the form

```
MAX(IFF(d.group_1 = 'One` then d.indicator, null)) as indicator1
```

This works as MAX takes the larest value, so if you only have one matching `group_1` per `customer`, the other will be `null` and those are not larger so the wanted value is taken.

If you have many, you will want to somehow rank then, and then FIRST_VALUE with a partition on customer, and ordered by something like a date..

anyways, if you have unkown/dynamic columns this can be solve using Snowflake Scripting to double query the data.

```
create or replace table table1 as 
  select column1 customer, column2 as _group, column3 as indicator
  from values
    ('Joh',1,'A'),
    ('Joh',2,'B'),
    ('Jane',1,'C'),
    ('Jane',3,'E'),
    ('Jane',2,'D');
```

```
declare
  sql string;
  res resultset;
  c1 cursor for select distinct _group as key from table1 order by key;
begin
  sql := 'select customer ';
  for record in c1 do
    sql := sql || ',max(iff(_group = '|| record.key ||', indicator, null)) as col_' || record.key::text;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from table1 group by 1  order by 1';
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table (res);
end;
```

gives:

| CUSTOMER | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | C | D | E |
| Joh | A | B | null |